# grails v.s cakephp

Tags: cakephp, grails, frameworks

I have an option to choose between Grails and Cakephp for my team to develop the next high- traffic website (hopefully millions of monthly visitors). Any suggestion of pro v.s con? thanks

Comment: This is pretty subjective if you ask me. What language is your team most comfortable with? What does your current stack look like? It really isn't about the tool being used, it is how you use it in the end.

Comment: Grails != Ruby or Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a big project (in terms of complexity, not number of visitors) and you are capable in Java, I think that using Grails will result in a more clean project, and easier to mentain / modify.

In the same time, although hosting on a Java stack has a higher starting barrier (needs ram and processor even if no request is made, and Grails projects must start with minimum 512 ram for a small/medium project to work reasonable) when the number of visitors is big, it handles them much better than a php interpreter (which would need a lot more processing power and disk speed on a high load).

Answer (score 1):

I have developed on both Grails and CakePHP. Grails is much more powerful. I can tell you that caching features on Grails are much more easier and stronger than cakePHP. This is the most important thing to keep in mind if you want to have a scalable web site. 
Another thing that the cakephp projects are not easily maintained, writing tests is very hard because you have to fill your fixtures with arrays. 
To implement cach using cakePHP you have to use the MemCache component, or I guess there is a new caching behavior but I don't know if it's powerful. In grails to turn on caching all you need to do is to add one line in your domain class.

The advantage of CakePHP is that you can do changes directly on your server without needing to export a new WAR and deploy it to correct a bug.

Finally, our company is migrating from cakePHP to Grails because of the big difference between them.